# Dynamic swapping of key/values in a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapreduce

I'm about to show the data I aggregated from the database in a grouped histogram.

The data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "Gas Separator Filter",
    "sellingPrice": 100000,
    "quantity": 10
  },
  {
    "_id": "Dry Gas Cartridge",
    "sellingPrice": 6005000,
    "quantity": 15
  }
]
```

But in order to show it in the chart and for them to be grouped, I need something like this. For each `_id` in the dataset above I should be able to see two bars in the chart.

```
[
  {
    "name": "quantity",
    "Gas Separator Filter": 10,
    "Dry Gas Cartridge": 15
  },
  {
    "name": "sellingPrice",
    "Gas Separator Filter": 100000,
    "Dry Gas Cartridge": 6005000
  }
]
```

It's been two hours and I'm not able to think of a good way to do this. What will you suggest?

Comment: @HarisBouchlis basically each _id is the name of a filter type, in order to group them in the chart and show sellingPrice and quantity as two bars for each filtertype name, I have to tell the chart that I only have two bars (two values) representing each object in the second array. Then I will give the chart the name of each filtertype.

Comment: Got it thanks, working on an answer

Comment: @HarisBouchlis Thanks, appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution using old school for loops :)

```js
const transform = (data, nameValues, keyProp) => {
    const result = [];

 for (const name of nameValues) {
  const output = { name };

  for (const value of data) {
   output[value[keyProp]] = value[name];
  }
  result.push(output);
 }

 return result;
};

const result = transform(
    [
        {
            "_id": "Gas Separator Filter",
            "sellingPrice": 100000,
            "quantity": 10
        },
        {
            "_id": "Dry Gas Cartridge",
            "sellingPrice": 6005000,
            "quantity": 15
        }
    ],
    ["sellingPrice", "quantity"],
    "_id"
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use array.reduce to achieve this:

```
const arrayToArray = (array) => {
 var ret = [{
         "name": "price"
     }, {
         "name": "quantity"
     }
 ];
 return array.reduce((obj, item, idx, original) => {
     ret[0][item._id] = original[idx].sellingPrice;
     ret[1][item._id] = original[idx].quantity;
     return ret;
 }, 0)
}
```

Like this you set a variable with the base object that you fullfill with couple _id:value for price and quantity.
But is not an "elegant" way to do this. Are you sure you need this objects array structure to show the chart?

Comment: FYI, this should be dynamically produced

Answer (score 1):

I find it hard to explain my solution but here's my take on it (you can add `console.log`s for different variables to follow the transformation ):

extract all the keys in the object, loop through them, the `name` would be that key, and use a nested loop to set the other keys and values :

```js
const data = [ { "_id": "Gas Separator Filter", "sellingPrice": 100000, "quantity": 10 }, { "_id": "Dry Gas Cartridge", "sellingPrice": 6005000, "quantity": 15 } ]

const [_id, ...keys] = [...new Set(data.map(e => Object.keys(e)).flat())]

// console.log(keys) : ["sellingPrice", "quantity"]

const result = keys.map(key => {
  const values = data.map(obj => ({
    [obj._id]: obj[key]
  }))

  return Object.assign({
    name: key
  }, ...values);
})

console.log(result)
```